# Conversion of pental to decimal, decimal to pental, adding base 5 numbers and multiplying base 5 numbers using def function

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

How do I convert a base 5 number to a decimal, a decimal to a base 5 number, adding base 5 numbers and multiplying base 5 numbers using the def functions:

- `gumatj_to_decimal(a)`, that converts a Gumatj number to decimal
- `decimal_to_gumatj(a)`, that converts a decimal number to Gumatj
- `gumatj_add(a, b)`, that adds 2 Gumatj numbers
- `gumatj_multiply(a, b)`, that multiples 2 Gumatj numbers

```
choice = input ("Choose test:\n")
action = choice[:1]
print ("calling function")

if action == 'g' or action == 'd':

    num = int(choice[2:])

    if action == 'g':
      answer = gumatj.gumatj_to_decimal (num)
    else:
      answer = gumatj.decimal_to_gumatj (num)

 elif action == 'a' or action == 'm':

    num1, num2 = map (int, choice[2:].split(" "))

    if action == 'a':
      answer = gumatj.gumatj_add (num1, num2)
    else:
      answer = gumatj.gumatj_multiply (num1, num2)

 print ("called function")
 print (answer)
```

Sample I/O:

```
Choose test: 
d 12 
calling function 
called function 
22
```

Sample I/O:

```
Choose test: 
g 22 
calling function 
called function 
12
```

Sample I/O:

```
Choose test:
a 12 14 
calling function 
called function 
31
```

Sample I/O:

```
Choose test: 
m 3 4 
calling function 
called function 
22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import numpy


def gumatj_to_decimal(num):
    return int(str(num), 5)


def decimal_to_gumatj(num):
    return numpy.base_repr(num, 5)


def gumatj_add(num1, num2):
    return decimal_to_gumatj(gumatj_to_decimal(num1) + gumatj_to_decimal(num2))


def gumatj_multiply(num1, num2):
    return decimal_to_gumatj(gumatj_to_decimal(num1) * gumatj_to_decimal(num2))


choice = input("Choose test:\n")
action = choice[:1]
print("calling function")

if action == 'g' or action == 'd':

    num = int(choice[2:])

    if action == 'g':
        answer = gumatj_to_decimal(num)
    else:
        answer = decimal_to_gumatj(num)

elif action == 'a' or action == 'm':

    num1, num2 = map(int, choice[2:].split(" "))

    if action == 'a':
        answer = gumatj_add(num1, num2)
    else:
        answer = gumatj_multiply(num1, num2)

print("called function")
print(answer)
```

**Example output:**

```
Choose test:
d 12
calling function
called function
22

Choose test:
g 22
calling function
called function
12

Choose test:
a 12 14
calling function
called function
31

Choose test:
m 3 4     
calling function
called function
22
```

**Explanation:**

- Converting base 5 number to decimal:

Python [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html?highlight=int#int) can convert strings of any base to an integer number:

```
def gumatj_to_decimal(num):
    return int(str(num), 5)
```

- Converting a decimal number to base 5:

Numpy's [`base_repr`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.base_repr.html) can do that:

```
def decimal_to_gumatj(num):
    return numpy.base_repr(num, 5)
```

- Adding two base 5 numbers:

First convert them to decimal, add them and convert them back to base 5:

```
def gumatj_add(num1, num2):
    return decimal_to_gumatj(gumatj_to_decimal(num1) + gumatj_to_decimal(num2))
```

- Multiplying two base 5 numbers:

First convert them to decimal, multiply, convert them back to base 5:

```
def gumatj_multiply(num1, num2):
    return decimal_to_gumatj(gumatj_to_decimal(num1) * gumatj_to_decimal(num2))
```